# Powershell Instantiating a class constructor with arguments

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell. I am trying to write a simple routine and it fails. The code and error message are given below. I tried quite a few combinations. What am I doing wrong?

```
$fileContent = Get-Content "ExePaths.txt"
foreach ($file in $fileContent)
{
    if($file.Contains("Executable"))
        {
            $path = $file.Replace("""Executable""=","")
            $path = $path.Replace("\\","\")
            echo $path
            $fileInfoData = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -fileName $path
            echo $fileInfoData.FullName
            break;

            ##echo $fileInfoData.FullName   
        }
}
```

Error message

```
New-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'fileName'.
At C:\Users\siluvaie\Desktop\Docs\Barcap\Projects\FV8\reg from prod servers\ReadFile.ps1:9 char:69
+             $fileInfoData = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -fileName <<<<  $path
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a constructer as you would in .NET. In your example you're passing `-fileName` parameter to `New-Object` cmdlet, not the `FileInfo` class.

```
$fileInfoData = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo($path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ArgumentList parameter:

```
$fileInfoData = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -ArgumentList $path
```

Comment: as long as $Path contains a valid path it should work. Tried it here at my end, and it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Get-Item` Instead of `System.IO.FileInfo`

```
$fileInfoData = Get-Item $path
```

Then

```
$fileInfoData.FullName
```